# Uploading video with Graph API, specifying videogame for footage

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I hope this is not a duplicate, I have been searching for some weeks and I am not able to find anything.
For context, I am the manager of a page, and I want to upload videos to it (gaming footage). I can use the UI, however, sometimes I have to upload multiple videos, which is a bit cumbersome. For this reason, I want to automate the upload using Graph API.
So far, I know how to upload a video, however. Some fields that I want to populate seems to be hidden, or not available, through the API.

For example, given the following screenshot as example:
[image: sample for video post edit]

I know how to specify the Video Title, video Description, and thumbnail. However, I can not find how the 'Game' selector (in this case, 'Grand Theft Aurto V') is set. Fields I tried to correlate with no luck:

1. *content_tags* field, but it includes other tags that you put in other form, not specifically the video game ID or name.
2. *custom_labels* field: This one has other kind of tags, which are used for something else, not the video game name.
3. Other fields contain mostly video metadata, and is not relevant to the Game field.

I also tried the Post endpoint, still with no luck

Is there any other field that may hold this? Seeing the Developer tools on the browser when a video is edited, it seems that the video game ID is passed, and Facebook does something under the hood, but I am not able to find it.

I am implementing this on Python, but using the Request library, so any HTTP call should work.

Thanks in advance!